# Php code doesn't work in CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I've been looking around the Net for a solution to using PHP in CSS, and I've found one.But it doesn't really work.

My "style.php" file:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css;");
$mainpicurl = "img/cars/mainpic/e38.jpg";
?>
body {
background:url("<?php echo $mainpicurl; ?>") no-repeat;
}
```

And yes, I changed the link to my stylesheet to .php in `index.html`.
But what I am getting is: http://prntscr.com/5qpddy

I'm testing on localhost, what am I doing wrong? Have I missed something?

Comment: `header("Content-type: text/css;");` Because of this you get that output!

Comment: That's generally a bad idea, now the CSS file will never be cached!

Answer (score 3):

Your screenshot shows PHP code being sent to the browser. Your web server is not set up to parse .html pages as PHP files, simple as that. Either set it up that way, or change your index.html to index.php

Comment: OMG, I'm using PHP in HTML.What a noob out of me :D Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

remove `;` from `header("Content-type: text/css;")` . the correct form:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css");
    $mainpicurl = "img/cars/mainpic/e38.jpg";
?>
```